# Estimating the parameters of ODE system using several data sets

Tags: matlab, parameters, mathematical-optimization, differential-equations

I have a system of 2 ODEs and I want to fit this system to some data in order to estimate some model parameters.

There are two data sets. I want to fit the model to these two data sets simultaneously and the parameters should be the same when fitted for both data.
The data I have is given as the total over a certain period. For example in `data1` the first element is the total of state A during the time period from 2-4 hours. So, for each tiem interval I have the total over that time period in each data set.
Because of this while I am simultaneously fitting to the two data sets I also have to fit through out the 4 time intervals (2-4,5-7,8-10,11-13).

If the data was given only for a single continuous time period such as time=2:13 I know how to estimate the parameters. But now I am not sure if the way I have implemented this is correct. This is the code that I have written.

```
%data

t=[2 3 4;5 6 7;8 9 10; 11 12 13];

data1=[5.399537437;6.762059387;7.34552533;7.675700967];
data2=[0.153279989125067;7.395870359956480;3.519156383296502;2.553056632299227];
%initial guesses
k0=[0.001;0.001;0.001];
lb=[0,0.0002,0];
ub=Inf*ones(1,3);
x={t,data1,data2};

[fittedVal,fval]=fmincon(@(k)ssq(k,x),k0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)

function error=ssq(k,x)
    time=x{1,1};
    data1=x{1,2};
    data2=x{1,3};
    error=0;
    for it=1:4
        fitted=model(k,time(it,:));
        error=error+(sum((fitted-data1(it)).^2))+(sum((fitted-data2(it)).^2));
    end
end

function output= model(k,time)
    b0=[0;3.13];%initial conditions
    [time,values] = ode45(@Equations,time,b0);

function s=Equations(t,y)

    s= zeros(2,1);
    rep=0.204;
    ag=0.3368;
    carrying=10^9;
    carrying2=1*10^8;

    s(1)=(rep*y(1))*(1-(y(1)/carrying))-k(2)*ag*y(1)*(1-(y(2)/carrying2))+k(3)*y(2);
    s(2)=k(2)*ag*y(1)*(1-(y(2)/carrying2))+k(1)*y(2)-k(3)*y(2);

end
output=values(:,2)+values(:,1);

end
```

To fit for all for data points I am using a for loop. Is this the correct way to go about it?

In this I am not sure if I have to accumulate the `error` within the for loop.

Also, because these time points are related that is when I am starting the time period from 5-7, the data from 2-4 should have an impact, I want to change the initial conditions for the ode solver `ode45` with the final value of the model results of the previous time point being as the initial conditions to the next time period.
How can I do this because at the moment at each `for` loop iteration I have b0=[0;3.13]